# Standard sharepoint approval workflow error

Tags: sharepoint-designer, workflow, content-approval

For a document library I want to make an approval workflow.

In the document library settings I have enabled document approval under versioning. I do see the approval status column in the list.

Then I wanted to attach a workflow to the library. So I went to 'Add a workflow'. **First problem** I don't see the standard 'Approval Workflow' in my options to choose from (text is in Dutch).

[image]

I went to Sharepoint Designer and made a workflow.

[image]

Translation of the text in Sharepoint Designer: start the proces Approval (2) for the content of this documentset with the users that are given in Currentitem:madeby

This workflow gives an error when executed. No specific error, just 'An error occurred in Approval'.

The Workflow is only executed manually.

**What am I doing wrong? Why can't I see the standard SP approval workflow and why isn't the standard approval workflow made in Sharepoint Designer not working?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to see standard SharePoint OOTB **Approval Workflow** then you need to activate **"Workflows"** feature at Site collection level.

Below are the steps for activate this feature.

**Site Settings --> Site collection features(Under Site Collection Administration) --> Workflows**

Activate it and then check.

Comment: Hi Sam, I know what you mean, I checked it in a demo installation of Office 365 and see the option there. Our Sharepoint environment is in Dutch and I can't seem to find it there: http://imgur.com/3d1Jcrh Oh, by the way, the live environment is on a team-website. Does that matter?

Comment: Have you find "werkstrooms" in Site collection feature?

Comment: I got it! But why don't I see an approve/reject button? http://imgur.com/a/XCMV1

Comment: Have you see edit button in top left corner of window?

Comment: You mean inside Word application?

Comment: No inside your browser window.